# Apache2.service failed in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

I am trying to restart apache2 server and I used the command below and I am getting this error

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Output

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

After that  I typed the commands as given above "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" and got these outputs but I am unable to understand it.

```
$ systemctl status apache2.service
```

Output

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-02-07 11:38:36 IST; 19s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9552 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: Output of config test was:
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.6.conf:
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server con
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Input

```
$ journalctl -xe
```

Output

```
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has begun starting up.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]:  *
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: Output of config test was:
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.6.conf:
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server con
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z apache2[9552]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 07 11:38:36 Aspire-5742Z sudo[9546]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 07 11:39:01 Aspire-5742Z CRON[9571]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 07 11:39:01 Aspire-5742Z CRON[9572]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/s
Feb 07 11:39:01 Aspire-5742Z CRON[9571]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Feb 07 11:39:17 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has begun starting up.
Feb 07 11:39:18 Aspire-5742Z systemd[1]: Started Clean php session files.
-- Subject: Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit phpsessionclean.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Input

```
$ apachectl -t
```

Output

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.6.conf:
Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action '-t' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How to i rectify this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're upgrading from Apache 2.2 to 2.4, as describe [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html), enable `mod_access_compat` with

```
sudo a2enmod access_compat && sudo service apache2 restart
```

or update directives to 2.4 version.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: are you upgrading from 2.2 to 2.4?, if so, go to the section "Common problems when upgrading" and check them.

Comment: no i installed 2.4 directly

Answer (score 0):

Before starting apache, you should use `apachectl -t` making sure your configuration passes syntax checks - which seems to be the problem right now.

Considering your error message, my guess is you're missing `mod_authz_core`. You might be able to fix with `a2enmod authz_core`. You may be missing other modules, check for `apachectl -t` output and ask google about an apache directive matching the one failing syntax check, ...

Comment: After running this command i got this ...

AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.6.conf:
Invalid command 'Require', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action '-t' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: The apache error logs may have more informations. Maybe checking php5.6.conf around line 9, you'll understand what's going on. Maybe you could remove /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.6.conf. AFAIK, that file is usually named php5.conf, yours wasn't installed by apache nor libapache-mod-php5 package, it's weird to begin with, ...

Comment: Also, ubuntu, systemd, ... the default php version is 7. Just drop all php references from your apache configuration, restart apache, ... then you'll figure out how to plug PHP.